# Why does `npx react-native init` downloads react-native to a temporary folder?

Tags: react-native, npx, gemini

After some discussion with Gemini, I have a question.

In short, Gemini says `npx react-native init` downloads `react-native` in a temporary folder and deletes it after `init`. Gemini also says that after `init`, `react-native` modules are included in the project and I can call commands like `react-native run-android` directly.

So the question is why doesn't `npx` install `react-native` to my project folder in the first place instead of doing the extra work of copying and deleting? What am I missing?